# Is it possible that this angle is $45^\circ$?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

[image]

With the information given, how can $x=45^\circ$? I just could not find a way it would be possible.

Comment: Neither can I...Some info seems to be missing

Comment: Where did you get this from...?

Comment: $ \hat{BDC} =45^{\circ}$

Comment: If the upper poing (Q? O?D?) is not fixed, $x$ could be a bunch of different angles.

Answer (score 1):

> $x$ is not $45^\circ$.

Let $E$ be the point of the intersection of $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BD}$.

If $x=45$, then $\angle DEC= 45^\circ$ and due to vertical angles, $\angle AEB=45^\circ$.

If $\angle AEB=45^\circ$, then $\angle ABE=45^\circ$.

But, if this were true,  $\triangle ABC$ is a $45-45-90$ triangle.

If this were true, then *there would be no $\triangle DEC$*, as points $B$ and $E$ would lie on the circumference of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The question must be referring to the angle at $D$. $\hat{BDC} =45^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 0):

$x$ is not $45°$.

But angle $BDC$ surely is.